# Verify User's Keycloak session

Tags: authentication, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have set up the **Direct Grant flow** to authenticate users using Keycloak. I am using the following endpoint

*http://localhost:8080/realms/{MyRealm}/protocol/openid-connect/token*

to get a token then configured my ASP. NET server to authenticate the users on my server. I authenticate the users using the *access_token* and the *AddJwtBearer* method to authenticate users.

My question:
What is the correct way to check if a user is still logged in to Keycloak?

I have knowledge regarding the following endpoint to see if a particular user is still logged into keycloak:

*http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/{MyRealm}/users/{UserId}/sessions*

However, this will require me to make a call to this endpoint for each server endpoint which becomes expensive. Thus, is there another method which can be used?

Note: I have noticed that when I sign the user out of keycloak manually(using the KC console) then the access_token is still valid and the user can still access the server's resources which is not desirable, thus a check for the user's session is required.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the introspection endpoint provided by Keycloak, I would use that to check if the user is still logged In.

The process is pretty simple:

```
http://localhost:8080/realms/GT/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect
```

- Make an HTTP post to the above URL
- Make sure that the request includes the  access token as a parameter, also the clientID and client secret in the Authorization header.

Something like this:

```
POST /realms/GT/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded client ID and secret>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

token=<access_token>
```

**Why this approach?**
To avoid the need to make a call to the `/admin/realms/GT/users/{userId}/sessions` endpoint for each server endpoint, since the introspection endpoint can be used to verify the tokens validity for all the requests.

**Users still being able to access server resources** even after signing out of Keycloak manually, you can address this by configuring the Keycloak server to invalidate all active sessions when a user signs out. This can be done by setting the `backchannel_logout_session_required` configuration option to `true`. When this option is set, Keycloak will send a backchannel logout request to all clients associated with the user, which will cause their active sessions to be invalidated. This option may affect **performance**. Depending on the number of clients and the network conditions, this may cause a delay in the logout process. If you have a large number of clients, you may want to consider setting up a separate logout service that can handle the backchannel logout requests asynchronously.

I think this should make sense and clarified your issue. Please let me know, if this works or not. I am curious to know.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is running the introspective endpoint each time a user hits my server endpoint? If yes then it is basically the same as calling the sessions endpoint each time a user hits a server endpoint because a API call will still need to make everytime. Also, how would I set the backchannel_logout_session_required settings?

Comment: Nope, instead, you should validate the access token once when the user first logs in and store the result, such as in a cache or in-memory store.

Comment: So I should call '...openid-connect/token endpoint' (which logs the user in Keycloak in). Then I should get access token and call  '...openid-connect/token/introspect' with the access token as parameter that I got from the 1st endpoint. Then I get information (I already have this information from the JWT token since I have ran this) and do what with it?

Comment: Yes, you obtain the access token from the /token endpoint, you should call the /introspect endpoint with the access token as a parameter to validate the token. This response do have information including whether it is still active and valid.

Comment: ANd it should be noted that, you should not rely solely on the access token for authorization. The access token is a bearer token, which means that anyone who has the token can use it to access protected resources. I assume you know that. Also to make it more risk-free, use additional authorization mechanisms, such as role-based access control or resource-based access control, to ensure that only authorized users can access protected resources..

Comment: Yes I added claims such as rolls to my JWT token so that it is secure. But the problem remains. The information gathered from the introspective or access_token cannot tell me whether the user's session is still active lets say 5 minutes after the user initially authenticated. I can log user out of Keycloak and user can still get access to my private server resources using the access_token. So the only solution I see is to use REST-API to call keycloak to ask for the session of the user.

Comment: Ok! I understand, making a REST API call to Keycloak to check the user's session status is expensive. Then why not "OpenID Connect Session Management" which I mentioned earlier. This will let you track a user's authentication session across multiple sites and devices. You would need to implement the check_session_iframe endpoint on your server and include the check_session_iframe in your web pages. The check_session_iframe can then be used to periodically check if the user's session is still active.

Comment: Let me check that out. Thanx for your help thus far.